# Error in a Lua script when trying to edit a resource of my MTA Server

Tags: lua

The error is coming in Lua when I start the script its a `.luac`

```
[10:04:36] Starting sqh_characters
[10:04:36] WARNING: sqh_characters/system/config/burlar.luac:31: Access denied @ 'fetchRemote'
[10:04:37] INFO: Modelos já foram bloqueados
[10:04:37] start: Resource 'sqh_characters' started
[10:04:42] INFO: Modelos já foram bloqueados  [DUP x2]
```

It should start right away I guess and it's encrypted and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm trying to run this resource and this isn't working and got the error I mentioned above but for my other friend its working.